# Why does this EventEmitter return an Event instead of a string?

Tags: event-handling, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I'm trying to communicate components on Angular2 and found out that using the Output decorator was the best way in my case, so I followed the documentation's guide and did exactly the same steps. Although when I try to log on console what I'm receiving from the child nodes is an Event object instead of the string it was supposed to be.

This is the child component that emits the event (TreeView Component):

```
@Component ({
  selector: 'tree-view',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let node of treeData | derp">
      <input type="checkbox" name="isActive" *ngIf="node._name?.length > 0" (click)="choose(node)">
    [...]
      </li>
  </ul>
  `
})

export class TreeView implements OnInit {
  @Output() onChosen = new EventEmitter<string>();

  choose(feature: string) {
    this.onChosen.emit(feature);
  }
}
```

This is the parent component that receives it:

```
<tree-view (change)=onChosen($event) [treeData]=myTree></tree-view>
```

And this is the callback that's called on the parent component that contains the template above:

```
  onChosen(feature: string) {
    console.log(feature);
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling the wrong event:

The event on the child should be 'change' instead of 'click' since it is a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="isActive" *ngIf="node._name?.length > 0" (change)="choose(node)">
```

The event in the parent should be 'onChosen' instead of 'change'.

```
<tree-view (onChosen)=onChosen($event) [treeData]=myTree></tree-view>
```

Comment: I thought so, and I tried it, but when it happens the event is never triggered and nothing is ever logged to the console.

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Nothing happens when I click on the checkbox.

Comment: I just found out what's happening. My tree-view has many nested components, since it's a tree, so the binding only worked for the 1st method. I just managed to do a workaround for this issue, thanks a lot for your help!